# Polynomial fitting and solve the coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, coefficients

I have have plot 'energy1' vs 'amp'. I wrote the following code to,
a) draw a 4th order polynomial fitting curve for the data set
b) get the coefficients of the polynomial

However, the function f1 prints as,
" f1= 29.16 x^4 + 9.809e-07 x^3 - 73.08 x^2 - 1.84e-06 x + 0.2619"

and the coefficient prints as,
"coefficient= [ 2.91632913e+01  9.80928536e-07 -7.30843650e+01 -1.84038399e-06
2.61942115e-01]"

1. How can I write the function with only the "even power" terms and then get their coefficients?
2. How to recheck/evaluate if the coefficients gives the correct "energy1' value for a specific 'amplitude" value (that will again match with my "energy1" data)?

```
amp=(['amplitude'])
energy1=(name['solar'])
p1 = np.polyfit(amp, energy1, 4) #polynomial
f1 = np.poly1d(p1) #function
x1= np.linspace(-1.6, 1.6, 100)
plt.plot(amp, energy1, 'b^', label="solar", markersize=12)
plt.plot(x1, f1(x1), 'b', linewidth=2.0)

print ("f1=", f1)
c1 = np.polyfit(x1, f1(x1), 4)
print ("coefficient=", c1)
```

Comment: So, you want a polynomial of the form `a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c`?

Comment: Yes, I want that form. @jared

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to fitting a custom function, I recommend using [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). You define the function with the first argument being `x` and the rest of the arguments being the variables you want scipy to optimize. Since the jacobian is easy for this case (you can easily take derivatives of the function with respect to each of the parameters), it can also be added to aid in the optimization. The first part of the return, referred to as `popt` contains the optimized variables.

The fit will be optimized, but not exact (especially when working with real-world data), so I am not sure how you'd like to compare the results. In the code below I compute the mean squared error and also show a plot of the actual data vs the fit. As per the documentation, you can also use the second return argument, called `pcov` "to compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters."

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
N = 20
x = np.linspace(0, 2, N)
a, b, c = rng.uniform(-5, 5, 3)
y = a*x**4 + b*x**2 + c
y += rng.uniform(-2, 2, N)

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**4 + b*x**2 + c

def jac(x, a, b, c):
    return np.stack([x**4, x**2, 1*np.ones_like(x)], axis=1)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, jac=jac)

print(f"Actual: {a}, {b}, {c}")
print(f"Fit: {popt[0]}, {popt[1]}, {popt[2]}")

MSE = np.mean((y - func(x, *popt))**2)
print(f"MSE: {MSE}")

perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
print(f"perr: {perr}")
```

Output:

```py
Actual: 2.7395604855596334, -0.6112156024794766, 3.585979199113824
Fit: 2.9453817011693193, -1.26046899494815, 4.061262973609011
MSE: 1.2228536711027866
perr: [0.19976097 0.74404971 0.48846652]
```

[image]

Comment: `curve_fit` accepts a `jac` which will improve the performance of this solution, and it is very straightforward for a polynomial

Answer (score 2):

I offer an alternative to @jared's (correct) nonlinear fit solution.

For certain kinds of data, linearization may be faster or produce a more numerically stable fit. The idea is to form a coefficient matrix where the independent variable is already raised to the powers you care about (0, 2, 4), and then perform a least-squares linear matrix solution. I encourage you to compare the runtime and accuracy of this method with the nonlinear method on real data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
from numpy.random._generator import default_rng

rand = default_rng(seed=0)
amp = np.sort(rand.uniform(low=-1.6, high=1.6, size=100))
artificial_coeffs = np.array([  # highest to lowest
     2.91632913e+01, 0,
    -7.30843650e+01, 0,
     2.61942115e-01,
])
artificial_poly = Polynomial(artificial_coeffs[::-1])  # lowest to highest
print('Target:', artificial_poly)
energy1 = artificial_poly(amp) + rand.normal(loc=0, scale=3, size=amp.size)

#  100x3           3x1          100x1
# [1 amp^2 amp^4] [f0 f2 f4] = [energy]
# [...          ]              [...   ]
fit = np.zeros_like(artificial_coeffs)
fit[::2], *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(
    a=amp[:, np.newaxis] ** ((0, 2, 4),),
    b=energy1, rcond=None,
)
polyfit = Polynomial(coef=fit)
print('  Fit:', polyfit)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(amp, energy1, label='experiment')
ax.plot(amp, polyfit(amp), label='fit', color='orange')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
Target: 0.26194211 + 0.0·x - 73.084365·x² + 0.0·x³ + 29.1632913·x⁴
  Fit: -0.08043268 + 0.0·x - 71.90597136·x² + 0.0·x³ + 28.5249142·x⁴
```

[image: fit]