# How to get the coefficient of the polynomial

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data set which I plotted and fitted the curve with the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R= -1.6, -1.4, -1.2, -1.0, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2,  0.0,  0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6
power = 486.040152, 343.466487, 233.706048, 151.069770, 90.792498, 48.455720, 20.748440, 5.267210, 0.080000, 5.267210, 20.748440, 48.455720, 90.792498, 151.069770, 233.706048, 343.466487, 486.040152
p = np.polyfit(R, power, 4) #define polynomial
f = np.poly1d(p) #define function
plt.plot(R, power, '<', color="brown", fillstyle='none', label="R(T=1.23)", markersize=12) 
plt.plot(R, f(R), color="brown", linewidth=2.0)
plt.ylabel('Power', fontsize='20')
plt.xlabel('Distance', fontsize='20') 
plt.legend(framealpha=1, frameon=False, fontsize='16', loc=(0.4, 0.75), ncol=1, handletextpad=-0.4)
```

The plot looks like this,
[image: plot]

However, this curve can also be expressed as the function,

```
f(T, R) = (a1 * T^2) + (b1 * T^4) + (a2 * R^2) + (b2 * R^4) + (d * T^2 * R^2))
```

How can I get the coefficient d (a single value from a fitted curve) when the following values are given?

```
a1 = -73.08,
b1 = 29.16,
a2 = 74.37,
b2 = 25.46,
T = 1.23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I explained in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76667009/12131013), you can create a fit for a specific function using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. In this case, you want to optimize a single parameter, so you can actually just use [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html). And like last time, the jacobian is simple to compute.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

plt.close("all")

R = np.array([-1.6, -1.4, -1.2, -1.0, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2,
             0.0,  0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6])
power = np.array([486.040152, 343.466487, 233.706048, 151.069770, 90.792498,
                  48.455720, 20.748440, 5.267210, 0.080000, 5.267210,
                  20.748440, 48.455720, 90.792498, 151.069770, 233.706048,
                  343.466487, 486.040152])

a1 = -73.08
b1 = 29.16
a2 = 74.37
b2 = 25.46
T = 1.23


def poly(R, a1, a2, b1, b2, T, d):
    return a1*T**2 + b1*T**4 + a2*R**2 + b2*R**4 + d*T**2*R**2


def func(d, R, power, a1, a2, b1, b2, T):
    return poly(R, a1, a2, b1, b2, T, d) - power


def jac(d, R, power, a1, a2, b1, b2, T):
    return np.array([T**2*R**2]).T


res = least_squares(func, 50, jac=jac, args=(R, power, a1, a2, b1, b2, T))
d = res.x[0]  # 50.37298613633045

plt.plot(R, power, '<', color="brown", fillstyle='none',
         label="R(T=1.23)", markersize=12)
plt.plot(R, poly(R, a1, a2, b1, b2, T, d), color="brown", linewidth=2.0)
plt.ylabel('Power', fontsize='20')
plt.xlabel('Distance', fontsize='20')
plt.legend(framealpha=1, frameon=False, fontsize='16',
           loc=(0.4, 0.75), ncol=1, handletextpad=-0.4)
```

[image]

The fit isn't great, but that's the best you'll get with the constraints you set.